# Tkinter 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, error-handling

im getting the above error when i run this code snippet. Im trying to error proof user input by creating an error window when the user enters a value not in a dataframe. the code im running is below

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import pandas as pd
root= tk.TK()
def customer_search():
    try:
        search = int(entry1.get())
    except ValueError:
        tk.messagebox("that customer doesnt exist, please enter a new number")      #error proofing has to be added tomorrow
        search = int(entry1.get())

    k = df.loc[df['UniqueID'] == search]
    k.to_excel("dashboard.xlsx")
    df.to_excel("check.xlsx")


canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

button1 = tk.Button(text='Enter a customer for analysis', command=customer_search)
button1.pack()
```

the error i get is as follows

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/....py", line 42, in customer_search
    search = int(entry1.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users...\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users....py", line 44, in customer_search
    tk.messagebox("that customer doesnt exist, please enter a new number")      #error proofing has to be added tomorrow
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It is a module.......maybe you need to use `tk.messagebox.showinfo()` and so on.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's the error you get? You should get the error `module 'tkinter' has no attribute TK` before you get the other errors.

Comment: jizhihaoSAMA that fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tk.messagebox` is a module containing multiple dialogs, you probably want to use `tk.messagebox.showerror("Info Title", "Info content")`.

Other dialogs are `showwarning` and `showinfo`, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

`tk.messagebox` is a module not a function. A basic difference between modules and functions is that:

- You can't call modules, i.e., you can't do `module()`. (*This is precisely the mistake you are making.*)
- You can call functions, i.e., you can do `function()`. (*This is what you should be doing instead.*)

You need to do it this way (in `customer_search`):

```py
tk.messagebox.showerror("Title here", "that customer doesnt exist, please enter a new number")
```

where `tk.messagebox.showerror` is a **function** in `tk.messagebox` **module**.